# Showing a Polynomial is Irreducible in Z8

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am in my first abstract algebra course and was working on a seemingly innocent exercise in my textbook that turned out to be much more difficult than I imagined.

"Show $x^2 - 1$ has two distinct factorizations into irreducibles in Z8"

It's easy to find two factorizations and easy to show they are distinct.

Those factors are $x + 1$ , $x + 3$ , $x + 5$ and $x + 7$

As I'm not in a field (or even in a domain!) many of my normal strategies fail.

One thing I have noticed and hope will help is that the coefficients of all of my linear polynomials are units in Z8.

In the specific case $x + 1$, if we assume it is the product of two non unit polynomials, then I force the constant terms of the two non unit polynomial factors to be the same.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I guess the point is that $x+a$ is an irreducible in $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$, and no two different ones are associates (equal up to a unit).  So you are basically done.

Comment: @Gregory Grant: I believe the question is how to prove that $x+a$ is indeed irreducible in $\mathbb Z/8 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @moonlight That's obvious since the leading coefficient is a unit.

Comment: I am asking how to prove $x + a$ is irreducible in Z8, for $x =$ $1$ , $3$ , $5$ , $7$.

I have noticed the leading coefficient is a unit but alas wasn't able to get a proof out of this. Any direction or hints? Thanks!

Comment: I've thought about it and I'm still not sure how to show that these linear polynomials are in fact irreducible in Z8. Could you offer some guidance? Thank you!